# Right way to delete kthread waiting while semaphore will be upped

Tags: c, linux-kernel, semaphore, kernel-module

I write a kernel module that uses kernel threads and semaphores.

I call `up(...)` function for semaphore from interrupt handler and then my kthread starts to execute.

```
static int interrupt_handler_thread(void *data)
{
    /* duty cycle */
    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        /*
         * If semaphore has been uped in the interrupt, we will
         * acquire it here, else thread will go to sleep.
         */
        if (!down_interruptible(mysem)) {
            /* proccess  gpio interrupt */
            dev_info(dev, "gpio interrupt detected\n"); 
        }
    }

    do_exit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The semaphore and thread are initializated into module_init function. Error checking was omitted.

```
...
sema_init(mysem, 0);

thread = kthread_create(interrupt_handler_thread,client,"my_int_handler");
wake_up_process(thread);
...
```

And during unloading a module the semaphore and the thread are removed:

```
/*
* After this call kthread_should_stop() in the thread will return TRUE.
* See https://lwn.net/Articles/118935/
*/
kthread_stop(thread);

/*
* Release the semaphore to return
* from down_interruptible() function
*/
up(mysem);
```

When I try to unload my module the one frozes into thread in `down_interruptible()` function, because it waits while the semaphore ups in interrupt handler. And my code never returns from `kthread_stop()`.

It seems, I need to disable the interrupt from my gpio, up the semaphore by hand and call `kthread_stop()` function. But it is a potential bug, because after the semaphore is uped by hand, the thread starts executing and the one can again `down_interruptible()` after its duty cycle.

Could anyone help me, please?

PS: I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148586/linux-kernel-how-to-stop-a-kthread-waiting-for-a-semaphore), but, it seems, this is not my case.

Comment: From [kthread_stop()](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re71.html): Sets kthread_should_stop for k to return true, wakes it, and __waits for it to exit__. And also very important: _Your threadfn must not call do_exit itself if you use this function!_

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you, I've fixed it

Comment: @Anisyanka, Could you please share your insights on how you fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correctly operate, your kthread should check "stop" status of the thread when waiting on semaphore. Unfortunately, there is no "stoppable" version of `down` function.

Instead of *kthread* use **workqueue** mechanism. Works already have all features you need:

- You can add a work inside interrupt handler (`queue_work`),
- Only a single work can be run at the same time,
- Using `destroy_workqueue` you can safetly finalize all works.

---

Actually, workqueues are implemented using kthreads. See e.g. implementation of [kthread_worker_fn](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6-rc5/source/kernel/kthread.c#L633) function.